# Unable to import praw

Tags: python, discord.py

**I tried pip installing: It worked but nothing else happened.**

```
Requirement already satisfied: praw in c:\users\william\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (7.2.0)
```

> Note: Im using visual studio code. But this still happens while using different IDEs, and python itself.

**Here is my error:**

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\William\Downloads\Rocket\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import praw
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'praw'```

Thanks.
````

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `pip install praw` command to install it?

Comment: heres all I did:

pip install -U praw, 
pip install praw --force-reinstall , 
pip install praw,

Comment: did it not work even after using `pip install praw`?

Comment: I tried it on my system...it worked for me